# Making a perfect auto complete TextBox in c#

Tags: c#, autocomplete

I have made a search text box and have enabled auto complete when the "by name" text is in the combo box.
The AutoComplete source is my .mdf database file. The auto complete works fine but there is one problem.

When I click on the autocomplete suggestion the text in the suggestion gets selected and typed in the textbox but along with the text several **'Spaces'** are also typed.

[image: Image of how spaces get typed in the Text]

So, next time, when I click on the textbox, the Ibeam doesn't start from the last letter of text and I have to **BackSpace** it several times.

[image: Image of how the Ibeam blinks at the place where i clicked Instead of starting at the last letter of the TEXT]

I think that I have missed some autocomplete properties.

This is my code that can be related to the Auto complete:

```
 private void vieworder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//I am including the load method because I think that problem may be caused because I didn't call the autocomp method here
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                lblstatus.Text = "Connected";
                lblstatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                lblstatus.Text = "Not-Connected";
                lblstatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }

            showdtgrid();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
public void showautocomp()
    {
//this is the method that starts the autocomplete

        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT cust_name FROM ordertbl ", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        AutoCompleteStringCollection autoComplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            autoComplete.Add(dr.GetString(0));
        }
        txtsrchbyname.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        txtsrchbyname.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        txtsrchbyname.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoComplete;
        dr.Close();
    }




 private void btnrefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 //the refresh button refreshes the datagrid and auto complete
            showdtgrid();
            showautocomp();
        }

private void search()
        {
//this method selects from DB when button is clicked
            if (cmbsearchby.Text == "By name")
            {
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT*FROM ordertbl WHERE cust_name LIKE '" + txtsrchbyname.Text + "%'", con);
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                dtbl = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dtbl);
                dtgridViewOrder.DataSource = dtbl;
            }
            else if (cmbsearchby.Text == "Containing")
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT*FROM ordertbl WHERE cust_name LIKE '%" + txtsrchbyname.Text + "%'", con);
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                DataTable dtbl2 = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dtbl2);
                dtgridViewOrder.DataSource = dtbl2;
            }

        }

 private void txtsrchbyname_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//I also included show autocomp method in the text box so I dont have to refresh everytime
            if (cmbsearchby.Text == "By name")
            {
                showautocomp();
            }
            else
            {
                txtsrchbyname.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the data type of cust_name? If it's nchar or char, then you're bound to have stray space

Comment: The answer by @OrElse should work perfectly, though I'd strongly suggest you alter the table to use nvarchar instead. Only use nchar if every values have identical length.

Comment: @Martheen I thought nchar and nvarchar are same. Are they not??                                                      What is the difference between them?

Comment: nchar and char doesn't store how long is the string you store into it. As a result, when you read back, you'll always get the string with padded space *if* the original string doesn't fill the whole allocated space. If you store,say, country ID or currency code where the length is fixed forever, it saves space (since it doesn't store the length). Otherwise for data with variable length, not using varchar or ncarchar means you're wasting space instead, and constantly need to trim everywhere. Plus it also mean one can't store trailing space when they really want to, since it will be trimmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue comes from the database type of `cust_name`.
A quick workaround is trimming the result fetched from the database

```
autoComplete.Add(dr.GetString(0).Trim());
```